# Replace a column in a csv file using python?

Tags: python, csv

How to replace a column in `csv` file with a condition in `python`?

My `csv` file contains:

```
 34,2016-06-14 13:37:10,,1,,,t
 34,2016-06-15 13:48:20,,1,,,f
 34,2016-06-16 13:55:34,,1,,,t
 34,2016-06-17 13:48:40,,1,,,f
 34,2016-06-18 13:41:27,,1,,,t
```

I want to change the last column according to a condition. That is I want to change "t" to "1" and "f" to "0" using python program.

I have seen many examples but not with this condition and examples are little bit confusing.

I tried a little bit but it is not working. I also don't know if it is correct method or not

```
f = open('/home/rck/Desktop/attendance/month.csv','rb')
fo = open('/home/rck/Desktop/attendance/demo.csv','wb')

for line in f:
    bits = line.split(',')

if bits[5] == '"t"':
    bits[5] = '"1"'    
elif bits[5] == '"f"':
    bits[5] = '"0"'
fo.write( ','.join(bits) )

f.close()
fo.close()
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks....

Comment: Could you show your attempts, this is very trivial to do

Comment: Did you tried any csv modules in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your example there are 7 elements to the bits array, so you need to test `bits[6]` not `bits[5]`.
If you know you always want the last one, `bits[-1]` would work.

Also, I don't think your quoting `'"t"'` is correct. I fared better with `'t'`.

Finally, the last element (for me anyway) contains the newline character.
So to achieve a match I changed the tests to this form:

```
    if bits[-1] == 't\n':
```

This then worked for me.
rafalmp's answer works as it does a search and replace on the whole line looking for the character 't' followed by a newline, which it is.

One design difference however is that when using code based on your example, if the code encounters an unknown character (not a 't' or an 'f') it would leave the character unaltered. rafalmp's code would always change it to a '0' if it were not a 't'.
to have the same effect in your example, change the `elif` line to an `else` with no supplemental test.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression to do the job:

```
import re

for line in f:
    line = re.sub('\w$', lambda x: '"1"' if x.group(0) == 't' else '"0"', line)
    fo.write(line)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The code changes the value but it changes 't' as '0' not '1'  I have changed the line to "line = re.sub('\w$', lambda x: '0' if x == 't' else '1', line)" now it changes the 't' to '1'.

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake in the lambda function - now it works as it should.

Comment: @sathish, please check the edit made by rafalmp. `x.group(0)` should be compared and not `x`

Comment: But it also changes the 'f' to '1'. It changes only the else part. If I give else as 0 it changes both the 't' and 'f' to 0 and it is same as for 1 both changes to 1

Answer (score 0):

Unless you insist on `python`, it would easily be done with `awk` as following:

```
awk '{$7= $7=="t" ? "1" : "0"}1' FS=',' OFS=',' month.csv
```

where replace 7th column with 0/1 using ternary and `FS` (field separator) and `OFS` (output field separator) is `,`.